# Wrong Syntax in PHP/HTML - Parse Error

Tags: php, html, schema

I am trying to add in some Schema into my page for a specific part of it.  I have never done Schema nor put into PHP.

I am getting a parse error and I can't see what I have done wrong, can anyone help.

```
$allpolicies_arr[] = '<span itemprop="name">'. $policyvalue->PolicyName.'</span>' ;
$str_policy_details .= '<div class="col-sm-8 no-justify"><span itemprop="author"><p>'.Thats Insurance .'</span><span itemprop="itemReviewed">'.Rating for .ucfirst($policyvalue->PolicyName).':</span></p> </div>'; 
$str_policy_details .= '<div class="col-sm-4 "><span itemprop="ratingValue"><p>'.get_star_rating_text($policyvalue->StarRating_StarRatingID).'</span></p></div>';
$str_policy_details .= '</div>';
```

Comment: Can you please show All the error message, and identify the line number on the error mesage in your code

Comment: The code in line 2 has single quotes in wrong places

Answer (score 1):

THis line is wrong, you are putting test into the string but its not inside a quote

```
$str_policy_details .= '<div class="col-sm-8 no-justify"><span itemprop="author"><p>'.Thats Insurance .'</span><span itemprop="itemReviewed">'.Rating for .ucfirst($policyvalue->PolicyName).':</span></p> </div>';
```

Try

```
$str_policy_details .= '<div class="col-sm-8 no-justify"><span itemprop="author"><p>Thats Insurance </span><span itemprop="itemReviewed">Rating for '.ucfirst($policyvalue->PolicyName).':</span></p> </div>';
```